# ng-options and updating model

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Under the following scenario, when a client is selected, I would like to update in the gallery model. How do I update the gallery model with the selected client?

```
<form novalidate>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="galleryName">Gallery Name:</label>
                <input value="{{gallery.galleryName}}" id="galleryName" type="text" ng-model="gallery.galleryName">
                <p>{{gallery}}</p>
            </div><!-- /control-group -->

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="clientName">Client Name:</label>
                <select name="client" ng-model="clientList" ng-options="client.id as client.clientName for client in clients" >
                    <option value="">Choose Client</option>
                </select>
                {{clientList}}
            </div>
        </form>
```

Example of the gallery model:

```
{"id":"57","galleryName":"Sam","clientRef":"205","client":"245","favorited":"1","timestamp":"1374524146"}
```

My goal is to change the "client" when the clientList is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$watch`, and you could do something like this

```
$scope.$watch('clientList', function (oldValue, newValue) {
    $scope.gallery.client = newValue; //newValue is the client.id
});
```

Btw, you should rename `clientList` to something else, since what you select is only **one** item.

Comment: Understood, and with the $scope.$watch, would that be best placed in a directive?

Comment: For your implementation, put it in controller.

Comment: thanks for the help on this. This is a little creep on the question, but hanging me on this implementation. I need to access the scope.gallery in this promise $scope.galleryCollection.then(function(galleries){
   $scope.gallery = galleries.thisGal;
  });, haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: You swapped old and new value as per v1.3